# Getting syntax error in sqlite3?

Tags: ios7, sqlite

I m trying to store two values in database but i m getting syntax error 
here my code

```
- (IBAction)LogIn:(id)sender {
sqlite3 *dbConnection;
sqlite3_stmt *statement = Nil;
if (sqlite3_open([[sharedobj getSandboxPath] UTF8String], &dbConnection) == SQLITE_OK) {
NSString *insertQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO LOGINVALUES ('%@','%@')",self.userNameField.text,self.passwordField.text];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbConnection, [insertQuery UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [self.userNameField.text UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [self.passwordField.text UTF8String], -1, NULL);

    }

    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSLog(@"successfully inserted a record in table");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"error is %s",sqlite3_errmsg(dbConnection));
    }
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close(dbConnection);
```

}
 but i m getting

```
error is near ")": syntax error
```

How can i fix this error?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `LOGIN` is your table name, you need whitespace between `LOGIN` and `VALUES`.

As of now the `LOGINVALUES` is taken as a table name and the parentheses list column names to insert to. Then the SQL input ends without compelting an `INSERT` query, e.g. the `VALUES (...)` part.

Also, add a semicolon `;` at the end.